# Pass a string of less to less.js and receive css?

Tags: javascript, css, less

Is there a function in less.js to pass a string of less code and return css code? I'm hoping to make a live less editing environment, so the user could edit the less string and I can recompile it and display the css. I see there is a php solution: http://leafo.net/lessphp/ but would like to stay in js if it's a possibility. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can instantiate the less.Parser. Looking at the [browser.js source](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/blob/master/lib/less/browser.js#L99) it actually turned out to be quite easy:

```
var cssString = '@color: #FFFF00; body { color: @color; }';
new(less.Parser)().parse(cssString, function (e, tree) {
    var css = tree.toCSS();
    alert(css);
});
```