# Any way to inject values into Less files in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, less

I am working on a project where we want the user to be able to define custom colors. We are running the latest version of Meteor with, among others, the less package.

Right now all colors are variables located in a single theme.lessimport file which is included early in processing. All colors throughout the site (and many subsequent less files) are generated from these few variables.

The idea was to just generate a new userTheme.lessimport file for each user that, if present, could be imported just after the theme.lessimport file to override the variables with custom values. It all works beautifully and flawlessly if you physically add the file to the directory, but I can't seem to even think of a way to do it dynamically/programmatically.

I'm starting to wonder if this can even be done with less.

- one of the big hang-ups is that so much of the css is derived from these variables—including CSS included with our own app's plugins/modules.
- it appears that you can't import a remote file for inclusion in less pre-processing... so the file can't be generated on a remote server (this would be the ideal situation for our situation as user data will exist on an API server).
- there doesn't seem to be any programmatic way to generate or otherwise inject any values into less—at least on Meteor—as I can't find any way to interact with the less through JS.

Aside from this inconvenience, less has been perfect for what we're doing, so I *really* want to make this work. Hoping someone out there has some wisdom or direction they can impart.

Comment: The Less compiler is written in JavaScript, and it supports client-side interpretation.  Is it necessary that the code is compiled on the server side?  [See This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316385/pass-a-string-of-less-to-less-js-and-receive-css)

Comment: I was hoping that there would be a way with Meteor's built less package which automatically grabs any less files, compiles them, and serves them to clients. We may end up having to move it over to a more "manual" client-based solution.

Comment: Your .less is compiled at package time -- before Meteor is run and before any client connects. You're going to want to come up with a different strategy for this.

Comment: You could do the base Css with meteor packages. Then render an overlay with a http request. Such as create a webserver like this       httpServer = Npm.require('http'); and then compile less>css with the standard node less compiler.

Comment: Maybe the official "CSS variables" will also solve your issues? They are very exposed thus can be manipulated easily. Not quite ready for prime time yet, though: http://caniuse.com/css-variables

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how the [bootstrap3-less](https://github.com/simison/bootstrap3-less) package implements variables and mixins. Specifically the Advanced Usage section of their README.

"If you want to @import a file, give it the extension .import.less to prevent Meteor from processing it independently." So in your instance you'll name your theme file: theme.import.less

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do it. Just use the "fs" node module.

Here's a rather stupid example. There are lots of gotchas when you do it, but for a basic proof-of-concept, check this.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.hello.greeting = function () {
        return "Welcome to less_injector_meteor_test.";
    };

    Template.hello.events({
        'click #button': function () {
            var css = "body {background: " + $("#color").val() + ";}";
            Meteor.call("writeToUserThemeFile", css);
        }
    });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.methods({
        "writeToUserThemeFile" :function(css) {
            var fs = Npm.require("fs");
            var path = "/Users/charnjitsingh/Desktop/less_injector_meteor_test";
            fs.writeFile(path+"/user_theme.less", css, function(err) {
                console.log("WRITING FILE");
                if (err) {
                    console.log("ERROR WHEN WRITING", err);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```